# How to access and click button of popup window?

Tags: javascript

i am working on adf.ly link bypasser i am using popup window but i have one problem the problem is if i first goto adf.ly and run code from google chrome console it's work but if i first don't goto adf.ly and run my code in for example google.com chrome window console then it's stop working i want to click the skip button without going to adf.ly from just the popup window my skiper code is below:

```
var newwindow = window.open("https://adf.ly/DkcDx");
newwindow.window.onload = function() {
    newwindow.focus()
    setTimeout(function() {      
    if(newwindow.window.document.getElementById('skip_ad_button')){newwindow.window.document.getElementById('skip_button').click();;
    }else{
        //nothing
    }
    }, 8000);};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is **Same-Origin-Policy**. Basically javascript in a webpage *can not access websites on another domain*.

This is **why it is working** from an adfly page, but not from google.

An **option** would be to implement your skipper as a **Chrome Extension**, these *can get access allowed* to the websites you like.

Comment: I'd like to hear the reason for the downvoting, to improve future answers.